# Контент вылез за контейнер, как решить?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: gif]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #1E252B;
}

header {
  padding-top: 31px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-bg {
  background-color: #FF6E30;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  position: relative;
}

.img1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 47%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.img2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 41%;
  left: 60%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.menu-item a {
  color: #9A9D9F;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.auth a {
  color: #9A9D9F;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #FF6E30;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 400ms;
}

button:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title {
  color: white;
}

.first-title {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-top: 178px;
}

.first-title span {
  color: #FF6E30;
}

.second-title {
  color: #9A9D9F;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.form {
  padding-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background-color: #283036;
  border: 1.5px solid #252829;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.form i {
  color: #ADB0B2;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.form input {
  width: 500px;
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

.form button {
  padding: 15px 40px;
}

.icon {
  margin-top: 130px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 78%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon i {
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.items-header {
  color: white;
  opacity: 90%;
  padding-top: 200px;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}

.items-description {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 143px;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block {
  width: 392px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: url(../img/figma.png) no-repeat;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.block:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.block-title {
  padding-left: 98px;
}

.block-title h2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 78%;
}

.block-title p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFA537;
  opacity: 55%;
}

.block-p {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.block-p p {
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
}

.icons {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  opacity: 38%;
  font-size: 27px;
  left: 5px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.icons i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper-ib {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper-ib button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #1E252B;
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.block-title1 {
  padding-left: 98px;
}

.block-title1 h2 {
  color: white;
}

.block-title1 p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFA537;
}

.icons1 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 27px;
  left: 5px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.icons1 i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper-ib1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper-ib1 button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #1E252B;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.block-p1 {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.block-p1 p {
  color: white;
}

.block-title p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFA537;
  opacity: 55%;
}

.icons1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 27px;
  left: 5px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  color: red;
}

.icons2 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  opacity: 38%;
  font-size: 27px;
  left: -64px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block2 {
  width: 392px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: url(../img/vscode.png) no-repeat;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.block2:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.block-title2 {
  padding-left: 98px;
}

.block-title2 h2 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  opacity: 78%;
  top: 10px;
}

.block-title2 p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFA537;
  opacity: 55%;
  top: 11px;
}

.blocks2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 160px;
}

.block3 {
  width: 392px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: url(../img/Notion.png) no-repeat;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.block3:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.block4 {
  width: 392px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: url(../img/Slack.png) no-repeat;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.block4:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.block5 {
  width: 392px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: url(../img/ln.png) no-repeat;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.block5:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.block-title3 h2 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  opacity: 78%;
  top: 10px;
  left: 100px;
}

.block-title3 p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFA537;
  opacity: 55%;
  top: 11px;
  left: 100px;
}

.block-title4 h2 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  opacity: 78%;
  top: 8px;
  left: 100px;
}

.block-title4 p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFA537;
  opacity: 55%;
  top: 8px;
  left: 100px;
}

.block-title5 h2 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  opacity: 78%;
  top: 5px;
  left: 100px;
}

.block-title5 p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFA537;
  opacity: 55%;
  top: 5px;
  left: 100px;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  left: 470px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 17px 38px;
  background-color: #1E252B;
  border: 1px solid #343A40;
  color: #FF6E30;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.outline {
  background-color: #21292E;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  padding: 55px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.company-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.company-title h2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 80%;
}

.company-img {
  padding-top: 67px;
  padding-left: 135px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.company-img img {
  padding-right: 50px;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.company-img img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.tools {
  padding-top: 220px;
}

.tools-desc {
  width: 350px;
}

.wrapper-tools {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tools-title h2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 90%;
  font-size: 38px;
}

.tools-p {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.tools-p p {
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.btnn {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.btnn button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  right: 30px;
}

.wrapper-blocks {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper-blocks2 {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.tools-block1 {
  width: 288px;
  background: url(../img/zeplin.png) no-repeat;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.tools-block1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.tools-title-block {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.tools-title-block h2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 78%;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.tools-title-block p {
  color: #FFA537;
  opacity: 55%;
}

.tools-p {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.tools-p p {
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.wrapper-ib-block button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FF6E30;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 35px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  left: 110px;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.tools-block2 {
  width: 288px;
  background: url(../img/phpstorm.png) no-repeat;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.tools-block2:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.tools-block3 {
  width: 288px;
  background: url(../img/toolbox.png) no-repeat;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.tools-block3:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.tools-block4 {
  width: 288px;
  background: url(../img/pro.png) no-repeat;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.tools-block4:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.wrapper-otz {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.otz-img {
  position: relative;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.otz-img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.otz-p {
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.otz-p p {
  color: white;
  opacity: 78%;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.input-title {
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.input-title h2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-p {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.input-p p {
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.form1 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 550px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #283036;
  border: 1.5px solid #252829;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  left: 308px;
  margin-bottom: 240px;
}

.form1 i {
  color: #ADB0B2;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.form1 input {
  width: 500px;
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

.input::placeholder {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form1 button {
  padding: 15px 40px;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.container1 {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.first-block {
  width: 260px;
  margin-right: 170px;
}

.first-block-title {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.first-block-title h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 90%;
}

.first-block-p {
  padding-top: 21px;
}

.first-block-p p {
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.second-block-title h2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 90%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.second-block-ul li {
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.thirty-block-title h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 90%;
}

.thirty-block-ul li {
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.fourthy-block-title h2 {
  color: white;
  opacity: 90%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.fourhty-block-ul li {
  color: white;
  opacity: 55%;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}


/* 992px - 1200px */

@media (max-width:1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1140px;
  }
  .wrapper img {
    width: 492px;
  }
  .block-title2 h2 {
    font-size: 23px;
  }
  .icons2 {
    left: -33px;
  }
  .btn {
    left: 380px;
  }
  .company-img {
    padding-left: 78px;
  }
  .company-img img {
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .form1 {
    left: 206px;
  }
  .first-block {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .footer {
    position: relative;
    right: 70px;
  }
  .container1 {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1199px) {
  .container {
    width: 960px;
  }
  .wrapper img {
    width: 480px;
  }
  .form1 {
    display: none;
  }
  .container1 {
    width: auto;
  }
  /* .block2
    {
        width: auto;
    } */
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
  .container {
    width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .container {
    width: 540px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.5.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <div class="logo-bg">
          <img class="img1" src="img/Subtractss-1.svg" alt="">
          <img class="img2" src="img/Subtractss.svg" alt="">
          <div class="logo">
            <h1>antools.</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item">
          <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Home</a>
          <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Categories</a>
          <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">My Collections</a>
          <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Blog</a>
        </div>
        <div class="auth">
          <a href="https://rusyaaaa.github.io/" target="_blank">Login</a>
          <button>Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <section class="title">
          <div class="first-title">
            <h1>Awesome tools for<br> Designer & Developer<span>.</span></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="second-title">
            <p>Antool is a web collection of information on paid of<br> free Design and Development tools</p>
          </div>
          <div class="form">
            <i class="mdi mdi-magnify"></i>
            <input type="search" name="search" class="input" placeholder="find more than 430+ tools" required>
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
          </div>
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="mdi mdi-facebook"></i>
            <i class="mdi mdi-instagram"></i>
            <i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i>
          </div>
        </section>
        <img src="img/sd.png" alt="s">
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="items">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="items-header">
          Most Popular Tools
        </h1>
        <p class="items-description">
          Tools for the best Designers and Developers<br> most popularly used in the world
        </p>
        <div class="blocks">
          <div class="block">
            <div class="block-title">
              <h2>FIGMA</h2>
              <p>Free</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block-p">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-ib">
              <div class="icons">
                <i class="mdi mdi-heart"></i>
                <i class="mdi mdi-folder-plus-outline"></i>
              </div>
              <button>Visit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="block">
            <div class="block-title1">
              <h2>Sketch</h2>
              <p>Trial & Paid</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block-p1">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-ib1">
              <div class="icons1">
                <i class="mdi mdi-heart"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="icons2">
                <i class="mdi mdi-folder-plus-outline"></i>
              </div>
              <button>Visit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="block2">
            <div class="block-title2">
              <h2>Visual Studio Code</h2>
              <p>Free</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block-p">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-ib">
              <div class="icons">
                <i class="mdi mdi-heart"></i>
                <i class="mdi mdi-folder-plus-outline"></i>
              </div>
              <button>Visit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blocks2">
          <div class="block3">
            <div class="block-title3">
              <h2>Notion</h2>
              <p>Free</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block-p">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-ib">
              <div class="icons">
                <i class="mdi mdi-heart"></i>
                <i class="mdi mdi-folder-plus-outline"></i>
              </div>
              <button>Visit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="block4">
            <div class="block-title4">
              <h2>Slack</h2>
              <p>Free</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block-p">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-ib">
              <div class="icons">
                <i class="mdi mdi-heart"></i>
                <i class="mdi mdi-folder-plus-outline"></i>
              </div>
              <button>Visit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="block5">
            <div class="block-title5">
              <h2>Invision</h2>
              <p>Free</p>
            </div>
            <div class="block-p">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-ib">
              <div class="icons">
                <i class="mdi mdi-heart"></i>
                <i class="mdi mdi-folder-plus-outline"></i>
              </div>
              <button>Visit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn">Load more</button>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас классы `.block...` указаны с жестко фиксированой шириной: `width: 392px;` из-за чего они немного не влазят. Попробуйте заменить на `max-width: 392px;`, например:

```
.block5
{
    max-width: 392px;
   //.....
}
```